# Efficiently print an Array to text in Haskell (bogus, sorry)

Tags: arrays, performance, haskell

**Update 2**: This question is bogus. I apologize. I added some code to print an array, skipping the rest of my program logic, and it is nearly instantaneous. What I though was slow array printing must have been slow {something} that was lazily computed after the array-print function was entered.

**Update 1**: The snippet below does not faithfully reproduce the performance problem in my original problem. I must have misattributed the source of the slowness, either due to mis-tracking lazuy evaulation,  or some other change that I made when extricating the small snippet from the larger program. I will try to create a self-contained reproduction of the slow processing.

**Summary:**
Formatting an Unboxed Array of Int32 to String, and printing the resulting ~4MB of text to disk, is inefficient, about 1 minute to print 1 million values (60K CPU cycles per value). Why? Can it be made faster?

**Details:**

Running as a compiled program with "-O2" compiler flag. GHC 7.0.4, Haskell Platform 2011.04, Windows 7 x64.

I have a Haskell program that builds an array of size 100K to 1 Million `Int32` values.

The `Int32` values are actually `Int8` 4-tuple values `(Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8)` packed into an `Int32` in a (perhaps misguided) attempt at efficiency.

I am using [STUArray](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/base/Data-Array-ST.html) (but that might be a poor choice) to store and mutate the array.

At certain points in my program, I print the array to disk, in this form:

```
byte byte byte ...
```

where each byte is an ASCII representation of a decimate value of a byte ("0" to "255"). Example:

```
0 255 128 5 31 ...
```

My problem is that the IO action of printing the array to a `Handle` is slow: **It takes about a minute to format print the ~1Million bytes to text on the file handle**, on a modern 3.3GHz i5 CPU and SSD disk.

My printing code is basically this:

> import Data.Array.Unboxed
> import System.IO
> import Contol.Monad
> import Data.Bits
>
> printArray handle frozenArray = [mapM](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM_)_ ([hPutStr](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO.html#g:19) handle . showPacked . (frozenArray !)) [0..arrayLength]

```
showPacked x = (' ':) .  (shows $ (shift x (-24)) .&. 255) 
           . (' ':) .  (shows $ (shift x (-16)) .&. 255)
           . (' ':) .  (shows $ (shift x  (-8)) .&. 255) 
           . (' ':) .  (shows $        x        .&. 255)
           $ ""
```

**Is there a better way?**

What's likely to be the source of the problem? I have a few guesses (in decreasing order of likelihood):

- Formatting each Int32 with my code is inefficient.
- mapM_ over the array with (!) inefficient.
- Calling hPutStr a million times is inefficient.
- 1 minute to print 1 million values actually is efficient.

Potential red herring warning: There is some risk that the delay I see is related to lazy computation that is forced only when I print, and not caused by formating/printing itself, but I don't think so, because even when I print the array in the first iteration (after creating an initial blank array), it's still slow. And I can watch the output file grow slowly, so a lot of work is happening after the first byte is printed, even using a strict unboxed array.

Comment: A naive `writeFile "out.txt" . unwords . map show $ [x \`mod\` 256 | x <- [1..4000000]]` from GHCi takes under 4 seconds for me, so you can definitely exclude the last bullet point.

Comment: I'm also getting less than 4 seconds with your code even on my slow netbook. Are you sure it's not something else that's taking the time here? Also, which GHC version are you using and on which platform?

Comment: @hammar: I'm not *sure*. It's a lot of work (for me!) to speculatively change the structure to look for perf changes, so I can't do too many speculative changes. I'm at the stage where my program basically works but is slow and has subtle errors, so my next step is to chop it up into smaller individually tested pieces.  Maybe I was assigning blame to the wrong bit of code!  (GHC 7.0.4, Haskell Platform 2011.04, Windows 7 x64)

Comment: Can we have more code? Preferably the entire programme. My stub takes less than one second printing all that with the `showPacked` and `mapM_ (hPutStr ...)`. Would be interesting to find out what's really slow.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Obviously I jumped the gun on posting in a frustrated moment.   The entire program is several hundred lines. I'll pare it down to isolate the slowness.      I apologize for the mis-ask! :-(

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you *really* want to do that? Do you actually *need* this stuff in textual form, or would some kind of binary format be OK? Because if so, that's likely to be *much* faster...
2. If you *really do* need it to be decimal text, read on.

My first instinct is to avoid doing I/O with `String` values. Instead, try building the entire result string inside a lazy `ByteString`, and then write the whole lot to disk in one I/O call. As a benefit, the code becomes purer. (Assuming your array really is frozen at the moment you're trying to save it to disk.) You can then let the lazy `ByteString` engine lazily generate the text and do fancy buffering and stuff.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to get directly from an integer to a textual representation in a `ByteString` without using `show` to go via a `String`. But you may still see some benefit from it. Or not...

Comment: I need to eventually get the data to text. So I could print in binary and then convert to text later, using another program, or using either (1) non-Haskell (which adds heterogeneity to the project) or (2) a dedicated converter program that is somehow more efficient than working from the array?    Okay, I don't really need text, but binary format would involve making a change to the downstream pipeline to handle an alternate format.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a ByteString version, it didn't seem notably different, I think because I am still packing the Bytestring 1-3 chars at time. Bytestrings seem to me useful where the source data is already in contiguous blocks of  ASCII (or some byte format matches the Bytestring format)

Answer (score 1):

> What's likely to be the source of the problem? I have a few guesses (in decreasing order of likelihood):

- Formatting each Int32 with my code is inefficient.

So-so. I'm not sure how well GHC optimises `shift x (-24)`, maybe using `shiftR x 24` is better, but I need to look at the generated core to know. Edit: perfectly fine, produces `uncheckedIShiftRA#`, as one could hope for.

- mapM_ over the array with (!) inefficient.

Yes, a bit. Using `elems` or `unsafeAt` is slightly faster due to the omission of bounds-checks.

- Calling hPutStr a million times is inefficient.

Definitely. But has less impact than I thought.

- 1 minute to print 1 million values actually is efficient.

No:

```
Prelude> writeFile "IntList.txt" $ unlines . map show $ [1 :: Int .. 1048576]
(0.37 secs, 836888976 bytes)
```

It's far more efficient - and may well be more efficient than using an intermediate `ByteString` - to produce one long `String` which is printed to the handle at once. The String will be lazily generated, so it will not use much memory, and the generating of the `String` is pretty efficient (still tweakable if need be).

Going off to measure now.

Using

```
printArray handle frozenArray = hPutStr handle $ showit (elems frozenArray)
  where
    showit :: [Int32] -> String
    showit (n:ns) = (' ' :) . shows ((n `shiftR` 24) .&. 255)
                  . (' ' :) . shows ((n `shiftR` 16) .&. 255)
                  . (' ' :) . shows ((n `shiftR` 8) .&. 255)
                  . (' ' :) . shows (n .&. 255) $ showit ns
    showit [] = ""
```

to print the values brought the time to process `[0 .. 1048575]` from 0.9 seconds to 0.4 seconds. Allocation went down from 2,031,716,528 bytes to 779,086,856 bytes, but memory usage went up from 6MB to 11MB and bytes copied during GC from ~1M to ~5.5M, however, restricting the heap size `-M11M` to force earlier GC brought memory back down to 6MB and bytes copied during GC to 676,744. (ghc-7.2.2)

Comment: "It's far more efficient - and may well be more efficient than using an intermediate ByteString - to produce one long String which is printed to the handle at once."   This came to mind, but I had difficulty trying to make one obviously efficient string (without distressing calls to `concat` or `(++)`).   I'm not good at reading Core or profiling output to know for sure. I had hope that `hPutStr` would do some buffering equivalent to lazy `String` generation (since I'm not calling `hFlush` or printing newlines). Attempts to define and print a single `String` or `ByteString` were as slow.